# Microsoft Access using listbox with form value

Tags: ms-access

I have been trawling the internet for a working solution to my immediate problem, and whilst I have found what appear to be solutions they don't actually work.
I have a member form "Members" from a members Table. I also have a Children table which list all children. The members table has a ID Number field and the children table has an Member_ID field.
What I want is when you show a member in the main form, the listbox shows all children for that member. The Row source for the listbox is

```
SELECT [Children Query].[Child Name], [Children Query].Child_Date_Of_Birth
FROM [Children Query] 
WHERE ((([Children Query].[Member ID])=[Forms]![Members]![ID Number]));
```

All I seem to get is blanks. If I remove the WHERE then all children appear on all members.

I thought that maybe I need to refresh the query somehow every time I change members, but the first member to appear on opening the form has a child and even that one doesn't appear.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm fairly new to VB. I know this can be done but all of the site that I have found explain exactly what I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: The ' before Members is a typo

Comment: Incidentally, if I create an expr1: [Forms]![Members]![ID Number] it shows = in the listbox column so I don't think the ID Number is getting to the query.

Comment: What response do you get in the Immediate window from this? `Debug.Print [Forms]![Members]![ID Number] `

Comment: In the list box it shows the name, date of birth and the third column just shows the equal sign =. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Paste that line of code into the [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/immediate-window) and press the Enter key.

Comment: Sorry, at point event should I put the breakpoint to get into the VBA editor?

Comment: Just press Ctrl+g

Comment: The listbox is on [Members] form? Remove the form reference, try setting RowSource to simply: `SELECT [Child Name], [Child_Date_Of_Birth] FROM [Children Query] WHERE [Member ID]=[ID Number];`. Then VBA code to requery the listbox. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in naming convention.

Comment: Thanks, that works ok for the 1st member now, but when I click next for the next member it doesn't refresh. Do I have to code the re-query or is there a GUI way of doing it within the control/form?

Comment: Bingo. I put the requery in the code for the next Member button. Many thanks